# MS SQL Server Add '12-31' in Year (date field)

Tags: sql-server, date-conversion

After using YEAR (), I need to prefix '12-31' to the year of a date. I need this output in date format. e.g. date= Nov 22, 2018 >> YEAR (date)=2018. I need '12-31-2018'. Can someone help.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Please tag appropriately and show a little more of your code.

Comment: MS SQL Server- SQL is the programing language
code: YEAR (getdate())
Output: 2018 
Desired Output: 2018-12-31 or 12-31-2018

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the last day of this year, you an use:

```
select dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,-1,getdate()),-1)
```

If you only need the date and not the timestamp:

```
select Convert(date, dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,-1,getdate()),-1))
```